# Trying to pick data from a JSON response text

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing

I'm trying to pick some data from my JSON response text which looks like this:

```
{
   "status": "success",
   "reservations": [
      {
         "id": "22959",
         "subject": "SubjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-03T06:04:24",
         "startDate": "2017-04-03T12:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-03T17:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "17",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "codeName",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "buildingName",
                  "name": ""
               },
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2658",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "2446",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "3137",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "codeName",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "3211",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "codeName",
               "name": "name"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
{
         "id": "22960",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-04T06:04:33",
         "startDate": "2017-04-04T10:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-04T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "17",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "codeName",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "codeName",
                  "name": ""
               },
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2658",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "2446",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      }
]
}
```

I've been trying to use JSON.parse() and go through the response text with a for-loop with no success. I need to pick the subject names, room names, building names and both student_group names.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
var getData = {
                "startDate":,
                "endDate":,
                "studentGroup": [
                 ""]
            };



var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
           data.onreadystatechange = function () {             
               if (data.readyState == 4 && data.status == 200) {

                   try {
                       // Parse JSON
                       var json = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                       // for-loops
                       for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
                           for (var x = 0; x < json.reservations[i].length; 
                            x++) { 
                               document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
                               json.reservations[i].subject;
                           }
                       }

                   } catch (err) {
                       console.log(err.message);
                       return;
                   }
               }
           };           

            // JSON query
           data.open("POST", "URL", true, "APIKEY", "PASS");
           data.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           data.send(JSON.stringify(getData));
```

This only prints the last subject name if I have more than 1 of them.

How should I do this?

Comment: What have you already tried to get your data, you did not post any code regarding that.

Comment: I tried to get the subject name with `for (var i = 0; i < data.responseText.length; i++) {document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = json.reservations[i].subject; }` but if i have more than 1 subject it will only print the last one. @PawelGradecki

Comment: Instead of putting this in the comment, update your question with the code. You are iterating through your responseText, your should be iterating over your reservations so instead of `i<data.responseText.length` go for `json.reservations[i].length`

Comment: @PawelGradecki Updated the code, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat your parsed data as an object, so to get you going, this will get all unique student group names from all returned resources:

```
var studentGroups = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
    if(json.reservations[i].resources != null){
        for(var j = 0; j < json.reservations[i].resources.length; j++){
            var resource = json.reservations[i].resources[j];
            if(resource.type === "student_group"){
                if(studentGroups.indexOf("groupName"))
                    studentGroups.push(resource.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I'm not sure in what format you want to get your result (should this be a flat array or maybe another JSON, maybe only first value is important for you?), but I think you should already have an idea how to handle the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your data parsed, forget it once was JSON. Now you have a JavaScript object.

- Check `data.status` to make sure everything went well.
- Loop over `data.reservations` and, inside that, over `data.reservations[i].resources`.